# How can I display values in Power BI 100% Stacked Bar?

Tags: powerbi

I've got a 100% stacked bar chart that displays the percent of 100% for each stacked bar.
[image]

I can hover over each bar to show the value for that bar (for example 69.10% is 966 and 30.90% is 432).  Is there a way to display the value along with or instead of the percent?  So it would be something like "966 (69.10%)" and "432 (30.90%)".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no direct ways to do this. I have used a couple of workarounds which works fine in  normal bar chart. You can see if you can tweak this to suit your needs. The following link gives the details about the workaround:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-show-detailed-Labels-and-count-both-for-clustered-column/td-p/465975

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I tried to use a regular stacked bar but some amounts are huge for one bar and very small for others.  The 100% chart nicely shows everything even if the total for one bar is 2,000 and another is 4.  But if I want the values I think I'm going to have to chart it differently.  Thanks again!